# Which Control can is equvalent to databound list combox box of vb6 in vb.net windows form application

Tags: vb.net, vb6, datalist, databound-controls

I think there should a control like databound list control of vb6 in vb.net windows form application too which can show up data from database.

I have confused and staring my database applications in vb.net....

so can you suggest which control can be used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both List control and combobox control can be used for it. for that we need to set the datasource property and refresh it.

like

cmbbox.datasource = arraylist("item 1","item 2", "item 3")
cmbbox.refresh();

detail can be found in msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind lists in VB.Net, see the `(DataBindings)` field.

Comment: Which control is that... is that in listbox or combo control?